# binary mask for the coordinates using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, mask

I need to create a binary mask. I have some coordinates and I make those coordinates and inside that region equal to 1, and background equal to zero.

Here is what I have done, but the problem is ROI located not in the correct position and located on the right bottom of the image. I appreciate if someone could point me to the right direction.

```
function [X,Y, BW] = Create_mask(X,Y,im)


X = round(X);
Y = round(Y);

X ( X < 1 ) = 1;
Y ( Y < 1 ) = 1;


BW = im > 255;
for p = 1:length(X)

    BW(Y(p),X(p)) = 1;
end


for n = 0:(1/round(sqrt((X(end)-X(1))^2 + (Y(end)-Y(1))^2 ))):1

    xn = round(X(1) +(X(end) - X(1))*n);
    yn = round(Y(1) +(Y(end) - Y(1))*n);
    BW(yn,xn) = 1;

end


se = strel('disk',10);
BW = imclose(BW,se);
BW = imdilate(BW,se);
BW = imfill(BW,'holes');
im( im < 255 ) = 0;
im = imclose(im,se);
BW = BW * 255;
BW = im2uint8(BW);
% BW = imresize(BW, [256 256],'nearest');
figure;
imshow(BW);

% close all;

end
```

Here is the output the function:

[image]

I was expecting to be similar to this image. This is not the exact solution but it shows my expectation.

[image]

[X and Y coordinates are attached here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xhsmXULAPZaXrtlgd9sdzkkiIzcvmX6Z/view?usp=sharing), The first col is X and the second Y.

Comment: The loop over `p` is correct. I don’t know what the second loop is supposed to do though. If your results don’t match your expectations, maybe your expectations were wrong? What was the input you used to generate the figure you show? What output did you expect? All these things would help answer your question.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I edited the question to add more information.

Comment: Again, that first loop is correct, it sets the pixels given by X and Y. Whether X and Y contain correct data is something entirely different. The second loop still needs explaining, I don’t understand what it is supposed to do. Did you try leaving it out?

Comment: What is the relationship between your coordinate system and image? e.g. your `[X(1) Y(1)]` is `[671.25 622.25]`. Is it referring to pixel number `[671 622]`?

Comment: Sorry for not replying sooner. Yes, it is referring to pixel number [671 622].

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by calling function `inpolygon`, try this

```
function mask=createmask(x,y, cmin, cmax, dx)
if(nargin<3)
    cmin=min([x(:) y(:)]);
end
if(nargin<4)
    cmax=max([x(:) y(:)]);
end
if(nargin<5)
    dx=(cmax-cmin)/100;
end
if(length(dx)==1)
    dx=[dx dx];
end
[xi,yi]=meshgrid(cmin(1):dx(1):cmax(1),cmin(2):dx(2):cmax(2));
mask=reshape(inpolygon(xi(:),yi(:),x(:),y(:)), size(xi));
```

to test

```
xv = [0 3 3 0 0 NaN 1 1 2 2 1];
yv = [0 0 3 3 0 NaN 1 2 2 1 1];
mask=createmask(xv,yv, [-1 -1], [4 4]);
imagesc(mask)
```